What is this electromechanical device?
Can anybody identify the marked electromechanical component?
It is part of a mains-powered electric tower clock mechanism, circa 1980, and might potentially be part of rotation control, bell ringing or similar functions.  I'd have guessed a motor, but I'm confused about the the vertical square metal piece (1) with its touching circular metal wheel (2) with lozenge-shaped object (3) behind.
I believe the cylindrical object at other end of blue cable is a synchronous 220 VAC motor.



I can't see enough. And I'd probably dismantle more of it. But the lozenge-shaped object, if I am looking at the same thing you wanted me to look at, looks like one half of the rotor support system and probably has a nice bearing race in it. And another one on the back side, just like it. I am also flummoxed by the fact that the metal wheel is circular. Ignorant, I'd expect something looking like this to have an actual cam, instead. Otherwise, what's being "done" by the vertical square metal piece? So I take your question about that.

I updated with a labelled picture; will see if I can get better pictures.  I'm equally flummoxed; hence my posting.

Yeah. So #2 should not be circular concentric. At a guess. But I sure cannot tell if it is or is not from the view. Rotate the motor to see if there is any vertical motion with piece #1 as #2 rotates. If there is, then that's what it does.

looks like a grounding strap ... perhaps the bearings do not provide an adequate electrical path ... perhaps something else provides the other part of the circuit

It looks like a circular cam is mounted off-centre (below, in the top photo) to the axis of rotation of a motor. There's a cast counterweight behind to balance it.
The square tubing presumably would have a follower (like a roller) at the end so it moves up and down as the motor shaft rotates. Perhaps the reciprocating motion is used to strike a bell.
The particular angle of these photos makes it hard to judge the amount of motion.
If it was used directly to continuously strike a bell, it would be more like a fire alarm than a town clock striking. It's also possible that isn't actually a motor but some kind of rotary solenoid, in which case it might be able to deliver individual strikes.

I'm more inclined to believe rotary solenoid for turning the arms (via white dog clutch in first picture).  That little arm (1) is not robust enough to clang a bell.  I think the relays are for activating bell striking solenoids. I'm guessing there's a pin coming out of wheel (2) which is prevented from turning by arm (1) in the position shown as a safety mechanism and in normal operation arm (1) is removed.  I shall investigate.

There's a small synchronous motor that could be driving a large reduction gear chain inside the box to drive the shaft. Whatever that shaft does is tied to the cams and switches that are visible.

The rubbing on that circular piece could be intended as
a grounding connection, but more likely is just a friction brake,
to ensure that the motor comes to a halt rapidly when the power is
turned off.
The pin is easily removed when it is time to replace the rubbing
element, presumably a square rod sliding in the square tube,
with a compression spring.
